# find maximum difference in a postgres row

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, amazon-redshift

I have a table called compression that lists the initial size and compressed size of each item.

I'd like a query that shows me the best compression stored so far, something like:

```
select max(
    cast(uncompressed_size as int) - 
    cast(compressed_size as int)
    )
from compression
```

The problem is, this code won't execute because of this error:

```
 ERROR: Invalid digit, Value '2', Pos 0, Type: Integer 
   Detail: 
  -----------------------------------------------
  error:  Invalid digit, Value '2', Pos 0, Type: Integer 
  code:      1207
  context:   
  query:     362794
  location:  :0
  process:   query0_21 [pid=0]
  -----------------------------------------------
```

Something must be going on with the casting, but I'm not sure what is causing this.

It's a postgres database (technically amazon redshift), and I'm really confused why an operation like this might fail.

Comment: Why are you storing the sizes as characters and not numbers?

Comment: I only have read privileges for this database.

Comment: What is the format type of `uncompressed_size` and `compressed_size` column? I can run your query with 'character' type on my Redshift cluster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check for any extra spaces at the end or beginning of this character field values and try to trim it. If there is empty space in character then casting into integer will fail, so you may want to use `NULLIF(compressed_size,'')` and then cast that null value which should succeed.